# What do empirical studies from civil law countries say about judge versus jury accuracy?

Tags: jury, judge

Casual conversations reveal that legal scholars from different countries differ significantly on their view of the accuracy of judge versus jury trials.

**By accuracy, I'm referring to the *factual* aspects of each case (e.g. whether the defendant did kill the victim), rather than *legal judgments* (e.g. whether the defendant is justified in doing so).**

In the U.S., I often hear them cite studies that argue for jury trials, and I hear the polar opposite in continental Europe. They may both have their point, but I cannot help but entertain the possibility that they are both biased for their own system.

They are human; it is difficult to be 100% objective when it comes to such important questions where scientific evidence is not 100% clear-cut (e.g. such as in classical physics)

I've seen many empirical studies by U.S. scholars on this topic. I'm curious if you know about sources outside of U.S., and especially studies done by those who do not live in a country with a long tradition of jury trials.

Comment: If there was a way to measure that "accuracy", why would we need courts in the first place? What courts decide is deemed to be of maximum objectiveness possible. There is no further gauge to measure it against.

Comment: You should at least make an attempt to define what it means to be "accurate" w.r.t. judicial process.

Comment: @user6726 Just did. Please let me know if I should clarify further.

Comment: So "accurate" is when the fact-finder finds "did kill" if and only if accused did in fact kill, right? This leaves us with the insurmountable problem of independently determining in which cases the defendant did in fact kill, regardless of the legal outcome.

Comment: @user6726 Yes, because I'm not sure if "accuracy" is well defined for the "legal judgment" aspect (correct me if wrong). And yes, I'm aware I'm asking a very difficult question, but it is an important question, I think.

Comment: "Accuracy" is much better defined for questions of law, whereas it is completely undefined for questions of fact. Your question doesn't distinguish civil vs. criminal cases, which is a big problem since the 2 kinds of cases have different standards of proof.

Comment: @user6726 1) It seems to me that accuracy is *well defined* for facts (did he kill her or not). I think what you are trying to say is accuracy is *hard to measure*. 2) I see your question about standards of proof, but it isn't really relevant here: accuracy is defined with respect to whether the factual judgment is *correct*, regardless of the process that is used to arrive at the correct/incorrect judgment.

Comment: Not going to close because I want to see someone come up with a metric here that works. As it is though, this question relies on an omniscient observer.

Comment: @Studoku I think there are ways to get tentative answers to this question without an omniscient observer. Mock trials of made up cases would be one way. Because the cases are made up, we know the ground truth, and then one can vary the format (bench vs jury) to test the accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

### How can you tell?

A judge (or jury) delivers a verdict - how can you possibly know if it was the right verdict?

Even if the alleged criminal confesses, how can you tell the confession was genuine? Even if it was, how can you tell the perpetrator *should* have been convicted on the law - many people who commit what the general public considers crimes should not be convicted by the law.

### Aggregate statistics

While it may be impossible in specific cases, there are studies that look at false conviction rates in aggregate over a jurisdiction. For example, the estimates for the USA, a jury country, range from 0.01 to 4.00% (the wide range in estimates shows how hard this is). In Japan, a judge country with inquisitorial lay juries, the figures are orders of magnitude lower. But ... the USA actively looks for such miscarriages of justice, Japan doesn’t. If you look for something, you’ll find it (sometimes even if it isn’t there), if you don’t, you won’t.

Comment: Dale: I know it is difficult. That’s why I ask the question in the first place. There are still ways to get closer to “ground truth”, such as with subsequent DNA evidence, etc.

Comment: DNA evidence only shows a person was at the scene, not what they did and why. Not all killings are crimes for example.

Comment: Look, Dale, I know this is a difficult question to answer. But it is a very important question, as countries think about which system to adopt, so any research that sheds light on it would be helpful. Even if this cannot be done in actual cases, researchers can always run mock trials where we know the ground truth. The current attitude in (parts of) the legal community of "it is what it is; we don't know and can't know and won't bother to know" is not very helpful.

Comment: @JLi no country is “thinking about which system to adopt” all countries have a system that has, in most cases, been developed over centuries and continues to develop today.

Comment: There are civil law countries that are currently experimenting whether to add juries. It's okay, I think we have both made our points and there is no point discussing further. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If we could consult an omniscient observer who knows whether X performed act A, you might hope to compare the results of a jury trial vs. a bench trial do see whether one vs. the other trial type resulted in a better match between the omniscient observer's statements and the judicial finding. However, there is rarely any available indication of factual finding, separate from legal finding. [Here](https://govt.westlaw.com/wcrji/Document/Iefb0b251e10d11daade1ae871d9b2cbe?viewType=FullText&originationContext=documenttoc&transitionType=DocumentItem&contextData=(sc.Default)) is one example which asks the factual questions "At the time of causing the injury, was the defendant operating the motor vehicle while under the influence; At the time of causing the injury, was the defendant operating the motor vehicle in a reckless manner; At the time of causing the injury, was the defendant operating the motor vehicle with disregard for the safety of others". [This](https://issuu.com/stritmatter/docs/verdict_form) and [this](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DlTZDzzXcAErHmS?format=jpg&name=360x360) might be another example, which don't answer fact questions, they draw legal conclusions based on something else, presumably testimony. The first one is more clearly a legal conclusion – it asks about negligence by breaching the duty of a common carrier, which in itself is a conclusion of law and not fact. [Here is another](http://online.fliphtml5.com/tlge/xfjo/#p=1), a criminal case, which list the charges and ask "guilt" or "not guilty", which merges the legal questions and the factual questions. In general, criminal cases just ask about guilt so you cannot separate the legal finding from the factual finding. Civil cases ask more questions: you therefore have to treat criminal and civil cases differently (basically, you can't ask about criminal cases because the presumed information doesn't exist). Such information exists for a "special verdict", which is, as the name implies, "special" and not the usual case.

Apart from the lack of an omniscient observer to sort outcomes, there is also a severe lack of information as to the supposed "factual"aspects, separate from the legal aspects, indeed separating the two is conceptually incoherent.